# mongodb/node - update separate collection from a cursor - Promise condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections for sales data - one for cities and one for towns within those cities. I have sales data for town level only (by month) and now want to  add a new city.total sales field which will be the sum these sales for towns within each city.

I am using node to run a script.

1. Set a cursor on the Towns collection (aggregation) to group collection all sales at the town level. This works fine.
2. Iterate over the cursor, for each town find the city and add the value to the city.total_sales.

Example code:

```
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if (doc != null) {
        // debug - lets  just find an example row to update
        var city_row = db.collection('city').findOne( { "city": "Liverpool" }     
)
        console.log(city_row);
    } else {
        callback();
    }
});
```

The issues I am seeing - console shows "Promise {  }"

This is run as a batch process - not overly concerned with performance at the moment - what do I need to do to get the code to wait for the find, rather than asynchronous operation?

Answer (score 0):

Put all you findOne queries into a Promise array and then use Promise.all()